# React native - How to build app and run on device

Tags: android, facebook, react-native

Is it possible to build app and copy file *.apk directly on smartphone and run it there.
And I don't mean running on device debug version like on this solution:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html

Just copy, install and run like release version without signed APK.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Go to toolbar Click on Build -> Build APk